# rails: accepts_nested_attributes_for and attribute modification ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a modification form for an entity with an accepts_nested_attributes_for on a has_many relation. I want that when a single input is modified, the info is sent using ajax to the server.

Let say that we han an entity User, with a relation to post

Using jquery I can modify main entity attributes:

```
$.post("/user/1", data={"_method":"put", "user[name]":"My New name"})
```

However, when I use:

```
$.post("/user/1", data={"_method":"put", "user[posts_attributes][0][text]":"my modified post"});
```

The post is not modified, but a new post is created with the given text.
Do I need to include the post id?

Thanks